# System V shared memory in Python?

Tags: python, ipc, sysv, shared-memory

How can I make use of the `shmat()`, `shmdt()`, `shmctl()`, `shmget()` calls from Python? Are they hidden somewhere in the standard library?

### Update0

I'm after System V bindings that can be found in the Ubuntu repositories, or Python standard libraries (now or in future releases).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google finds [`sysv_ipc`](http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/).

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to use any non-standard Python libraries, perhaps you could wrap the functions you need yourself using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html)?

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://semanchuk.com/philip/PythonIpc/) offers a feature matrix to help you choose between the [posix_ipc](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/), [sysv_ipc](http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/), and [shm](http://nikitathespider.com/python/shm/) modules.

Comment: Does an ubuntu package exist for this?

Comment: @MattJoiner , There is no ubuntu package but can be installed via pip: # ```pip install sysv_ipc```

Comment: all 3 modules are absolutely trash, shm pypi page is empty, others 2 are not installable. And all 3 modules looks like abandoned. The best solution is to use ctypes

Comment: I did not have trouble installing the sysv_ipc with Python 3.8.  It appears to work.

Answer (score 2):

The [processing](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/processing) package also supports shared memory objects, and works on unix/mac/windows.