# How to store easily python usable read-only data structures in shared memory

Tags: python, shared-memory, wsgi, uwsgi

I have a python process serving as a WSGI-apache server. I have many copies of this process running on each of several machines. About 200 megabytes of my process is read-only python data. I would like to place these data in a memory-mapped segment so that the processes could share a single copy of those data. Best would be to be able to attach to those data so they could be actual python 2.7 data objects rather than parsing them out of something like pickle or DBM or SQLite.

Does anyone have sample code or pointers to a project that has done this to share?

Comment: "About 200 megabytes of my process is read-only python data." I couldn't understand this part. Can you provide some details? What data kind? What did you try?

Comment: What operating system are you using, and how are your processes forking? If you're using `vfork` then the child shares a copy of its parents' pages until it writes to them anyway.

Comment: Why wouldn't using Redis solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9991412/145279) by @modelnine on StackOverflow provides a really great comprehensive answer to this question. As he mentioned, using threads rather than process-forking in your webserver can significantly lesson the impact of this. I [ran into a similar problem trying to  share extremely-large NumPy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785275/share-large-read-only-numpy-array-between-multiprocessing-processes) between CLI Python processes using some type of shared memory a couple of years ago, and we ended up using a combination of a [sharedmem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17913222/145279) Python extension to share data between the workers (which proved to leak memory in certain cases, but, it's fixable probably). A read-only `mmap()` technique might work for you, but I'm not sure how to do that in pure-python (NumPy has a memmapping technique explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17880120/145279)). I've never found any clear and simple answers to this question, but hopefully this can point you in some new directions. Let us know what you end up doing!

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to share actual python objects because they are bound to the process address space.  However, if you use `mmap`, you can create very usable shared objects.  I'd create one process to pre-load the data, and the rest could use it. I found quite a good blog post that describes how it can be done: http://blog.schmichael.com/2011/05/15/sharing-python-data-between-processes-using-mmap/

Answer (score 1):

Since it's read-only data you won't need to share any updates between processes (since there won't be any updates) I propose you just keep a local copy of it in each process.

If memory constraints is an issue you can have a look at using `multiprocessing.Value` or `multiprocessing.Array` without locks for this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects

Other than that you'll have to rely on an external process and some serialising to get this done, I'd have a look at Redis or Memcached if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to create a C- or C++-extension that provides a Pythonic interface to your shared data. You could memory map 200MB of raw data, and then have the C- or C++-extension provide it to the WSGI-service. That is, you could have regular (unshared) python objects implemented in C, which fetch data from some kind of binary format in shared memory. I know this isn't exactly what you wanted, but this way the data would at least appear pythonic to the WSGI-app.

However, if your data consists of many many very small objects, then it becomes important that even the "entrypoints" are located in the shared memory (otherwise they will waste too much memory). That is, you'd have to make sure that the PyObject* pointers that make up the interface to your data, actually themselves point to the shared memory. I.e, the python objects themselves would have to be in shared memory. As far as I can read the official docs, this isn't really supported. However, you could always try "handcrafting" python objects in shared memory, and see if it works. I'm guessing it would work, until the Python interpreter tries to free the memory. But in your case, it won't, since it's long-lived and read-only.