# Message Queue IPC Python to C

Tags: python, c, ipc, message-queue

I have been using msgsend and receive from

```
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
```

for quite a while now.

I just came up with the question whether it is possible to join the communication from a python program.

Thank you

Comment: Check out e.g. [this older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219604/system-v-shared-memory-in-python) and its answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sysv_ipc](http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/) module provides API for using System V IPC message queues as well as other IPC primitives (semaphores and shared memory).